# Laravel won't send email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I have set my email function and I can get my form data but not able to send them,

#### Error I get

```
Undefined variable: name
```

#### My form data `dd`

```
array:6 [▼
  "name" => "tester"
  "email" => "test@test.com"
  "subject" => "testing emails"
  "issue" => "Other"
  "budget" => "100"
  "messagetext" => "hello there,"
]
```

#### Codes

`My function`

```
public function sendemailtoadmin(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, array(
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'issue' => 'required',
        'budget' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'messagetext' => 'required|min:10|max:15000|string',
        'subject' => 'required',
      ));

      $data = array(
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'issue' => $request->issue,
        'budget' => $request->budget,
        'messagetext' => $request->messagetext,
      );

      Mail::send(new ContactForm(), $data, function($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('xxxx@xxxx.com');
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
      });

      Session::flash('flash_message', 'Your Email was sent. We will contact you shortly.');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

`My email template`

```
@component('mail::message')

<p>
Name :{{ $name}}<br>
Email address : {{ $email }}<br>
Type of issue: {{ $issue}}<br>
Subject : {{ $subject }}<br>
Budget : {{ $budget }}<br>
Message : {{ $messagetext}}
</p>


Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Any idea?

Comment: check your .env file for email credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

I have changed `new ContactForm()` to `'my.view.address'` and used `HTML view` instead of markdown.

Answer (score 1):

There should be {{ $data['name'] }}, instead of {{ $name }}, in the email template.
The same applies for all the variables, $email, $issue, ..., in the template.

Comment: Undefined variable: data

Comment: No need for a closure to send the email. May use    
'Mail::send(new ContactForm($data))'

Comment: result is same, problem is my `$data` will not pass to my email view.